# Empty state of NavHostFragment of Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

**Background**

In app I have couple of NavHostFragments that are displayed in different parts of screen:

- defaultNavHost is used for switching between tabs
- inside one of fragments of defaultNavHost, I have another navHost for BottomSheets
- There is a need for another navHost that could display fragments on top of everything else (above tabs, above both of other navHosts). Imagine a tablet layout, that displays a fragment on top of another fragment, just by covering 50% of it.

**Issue**

A secondary NavHostFragment, as declated below, works as expected when setting nav graph to it.

```
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="false" />
```

I set the graph and start destination programmatically:

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
val graph = navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.navigation_additional)
graph.setStartDestination(R.id.navigation_additional_destination_5)
navController.graph = graph
```

What would be a correct approach to hide navController or navGraph? I want it to dissapear when I do navController.popBackStack(), but it does not work. If I just set fragmentContainerView to gone then fragment will still remain in that NavHostFragment and dissapear animation will not happen. What could be the correct approach to do this? Should the startDestination point to an empty fragment? Or is there a different architectural approach I should be using?

Answer (score 1):

The most adequate answer is to reload your fragment with something like this:

```
navController.popBackStack()
navController.navigate(R.id.destination)
```

But that's still a crutch)